# unable to execute a code which shows "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, automation

unable to execute code which showing staleElementException, to get rid of this i have tried the following relocating the element locator, webdriverwait,try n catch, and loop concept for which stale element is showing, i have tried all kind of these but  still i'am getting stale element exception could anyone help me to execute that code it may help full someone like me who is following this site.

```
    public void verifyToedit() throws Exception {
        test = report.startTest("Verify to edit Account no. of LedgerAccount Test");
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test Started" + test.getStartedTime());
        ledger = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LedgerAccounts.class);
        ledger.CompanySetupClick.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ledger.LedgerAccountsClick.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        s = new Select(ledger.SelectPayrollCategoriesLedger);
        List<WebElement> led=s.getOptions();
int ledselectsize=led.size();
for(int i=0;i<ledselectsize;i++) {
    WebElement select=led.get(i);
    select.click();
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    int editsize=ledger.EditActionBtnLedger.size();
    System.out.println("edit size is: "+editsize);
    try {
        for(WebElement r:ledger.EditActionBtnLedger) {
            r.click();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        for(WebElement r:ledger.EditActionBtnLedgerStale) {
            r.click();
        }

    }
}


}
```

IT showing exception in this line

for(WebElement r:ledger.EditActionBtnLedgerStale) {
                r.click();

Comment: any better if you say for(WebElement el : ledger.EditActionBtnLedger){//sleep (if needed)    el.click();} ?

Comment: i have tried it is not about thread.sleep statement,it is about "int size = ledger.EditActionBtnLedger.size();"  iam not getting the size dynamically

Comment: but with the for loop I'm proposing you should not need size at all. But size may be in it implicitly, and the failure could persist.